# Formal Markov property

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Consider stochastic proces $\left\{X_t\right\}_{t\in T}$, where $T=\left<0,\infty\right)$ and for each $t\in T$ $X_t$ can be continuous, dicrete or other random variable on same probability space $\left(\Omega,\mathscr{S},P\right)$.

If for each $t\in T$ $X_t$ is continous random variable and $T=\left<0,\infty\right)$, then Markov property can be defined (I think) as
$$
\forall t,s\in T, \forall B\in \mathscr{B}:P(X_{t+s}\in B|\sigma(X_l; l\leq t))=P(X_{t+s}\in B|\sigma(X_t)).
$$

Moreover, I think that equation does not have to hold everywhere, only $P$-almost everywhere. Because the condition probability is defined as the function which is $\mathscr{F}_0$ measurable and for all $G\in\mathscr{F}_0$ satisfy
$$
\int\limits_{G}P(A|\mathscr{F}_0)dP=P(A\cap G),
$$
where $A\in\mathscr{F}$, $\mathscr{F}_0$, $\mathscr{F}$ are $\sigma$-algebras and $\mathscr{F}_0\subset \mathscr{F}$. The existence of this function (of the conditional probability) is guaranteed by Radon-Nikodym theorem but only $P$-almost everywhere.

If I am correct and I use the definition of conditional probability in Markov property, I have
$$
\forall t,s\in T, \forall B\in \mathscr{B}:\int\limits_{G}P(X_{t+s}\in B|\sigma(X_l; l\leq t))dP=\int\limits_{G}P(X_{t+s}\in B|\sigma(X_t))dP=P(X_{t+s}^{-1}(B)\cap G).
$$

Is the $G$ from $\sigma(X_l; l\leq t)$ or $\sigma(X_t)$?

Can you recommend me some literature which deals with Markov processes in general not only about Markov chains?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Many books on the continuous-time Markov process have been published. A few of them are "Markov Processes and Potential Theory" by Blumenthal and Getoor. For connections with the Dirichlet form, see "Dirichlet Forms and Symmetric Markov Processes" by Fukushima, Oshima and Takeda.

Comment: Thank you very much. The first book is something what I have been looking for. But I am still confused if it is correct to write down that the equation holds only $P$-almost everywhere.